# how to make a php preview function to a page via codemirror

Tags: javascript, php, codemirror

**Target:**
I would like to embed a PHP editor with preview area in a page.

**Action:**

1. For this target, I search on google again and again.
2. I found codemirror (codemirror.net). I think it should be ok.
3. Downloaded codemirror zip (5.2version) and extract it to my computer D:\codemirror-5.2.
4. In D:\codemirror-5.2\demo, there are many demos, I found one demo(preview.html) is useful.
5. Open preview.html on Chrome, test javascript and HTML, it is ok.
6. I would like a PHP version of preview.html, so I copy preview.html and rename to phppreview.html in D:\codemirror-5.2\demo.
7. Open phppreview.html in notepadd++, and modify it as below steps.
8. Line 3, changed title to CodeMirror: PHP preview.
9. After line 12, add a new line :`<script src=../mode/php/php.js></script>`
10. Line 37 and 42,change "HTML5 preview" to "PHP preview".
11. Line 72, change mode from "text/xml" to "application/x-httpd-php".
12. Others keeps not changed,open phppreview.html in Chrome, test PHP code, it doesn't work,both syntax highlighting and php code output NOT WORKING!.

**Questions:**
How can I get a PHP preview in a page? What's wrong above steps or any other additional steps need to add?

Thanks in advance!!!

NOTE: There is no image as I have no enough reputation to post images, hopes you understand my questions.

Comment: Can you post your code or create a jsfiddle?  It's difficult to debug without any code.

Answer (score 0):

You have taken a javascript preview example from the CodeMirror example page.

Here's the link to that page: http://codemirror.net/demo/preview.html

The function is very simple. Whenever some code has been changed, the result will be shown in an iframe which is located on the same page.

You can do this only with html and javascript because the source is completely processed on the browser (client side).

If you would like to have a preview of executed php code you would have to send it to a server, have it processed on the server side and have it sent back to the browser. You would need to have some code on a server to do this work. Alternatively you could have php installed on your computer but even then the whole idea would be quite different to the html/javascript preview.

if you just want the phpPreview without devoloping the solution on your own here's a link: http://www.phpfiddle.org